# Unable to update binded datagridview

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am having trouble updating data back to mssql, if I query using the Case When, it would save back blank data instead the entered data. However normal query such as select * from table would not have any problem.

I have binded my datagridview and updating back to database with

```
 Dim adap As New SqlDataAdapter
 Dim cmdbl As New SqlCommandBuilder(adap)
 adap.Update(dt)
```

My table structure is as follow

> ID - int
>
> CarType - nvarchar(50)

SQL Query

> SELECT ID,CASE WHEN CARTYPE = 'TRUCK' THEN 'TRUCK1' ELSE CARTYPE END
>   CARTYPE FROM CARTABLE

Comment: You can't use a command builder if the required SQL cannot be inferred from your query.  Just create your own `InsertCommand`, `UpdateCommand` and `DeleteCommand` for your data adapter and you'll have no issue.  By the way, you should be using the same data adapter that you called `Fill` on in the first place.  You certainly can't use a command builder if your data adapter doesn't even have a `SelectCommand` at all. It's not magic.

Comment: yes, I did use a selectcommand. My question merely was just to find out why  using the case when would interfere with saving.

Comment: The code you posted shows that you're not using a `SelectComand`, so we won't just assume otherwise.  As for why it doesn't work when you use `CASE`, because the command builder can't infer the SQL required.